# HoloEverywhere pom.xml error

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-holo-everywhere, android-compatibility

I'm trying to setup HoloEverywhere along side Action Bar Sherlock and I'm getting the following error.

Could not find artifact org.holoeverywhere:resbuilder:pom:1.5.1-SNAPSHOT
pom.xml 
/HoloEverywhere Library line 1  Maven pom Loading Problem

Please Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run mvn clean install before importing into Eclipse. Or just remove maven nature from projects.

Comment: Thank the Maker!  That worked!  I right clicked Project->Maven->Disable Maven Nature.  I'm new to Android development (coming from iOS) so I have no idea what that just did, but it works.  Are there any negative side effects to "disabling Maven nature"?